# Sharing a MVC resources library between two components

Tags: component, custom-component, mvc, libraries

Lets say my component is called dumbo. It contains all kind of MVC stuff and works well.
Now i have a second component that is called jumbo. I need both components to share some models, controllers and views (and other stuff) from a central library.

Of course this is helpful regarding that question:

https://docs.joomla.org/Using_own_library_in_your_extensions/en

But it seams i have done something wrong.

I have setup a namespace loader:

```
JLoader::registerNamespace('Mylib',  JPATH_LIBRARIES  . '/mylib');
```

Here comes an example model and view from the central library that dumbo and jumbo should share and use:

Directory the model is in:

```
.\libraries\mylib\listings\model.php
```

The model itself:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\ListModel;  

class MylibListingsModel extends ListModel
{
    public function __construct($config = array())
    {
        echo "lib model";
        parent::__construct($config); 
    }

    ...
}
```

Directory the view is in:

```
.\libraries\mylib\listings\view.php
```

The view itself:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Toolbar\Toolbar;
use Joomla\CMS\Toolbar\ToolbarHelper;

class MylibListingsView extends JViewLegacy
{
    protected $items;
    protected $pagination;
    protected $state;

    public function display($tpl = null) 
    {
        echo "lib view";
        parent::display($tpl); 
    }

    ...
}
```

When calling the listings view from the dumbo component like this:

```
127.0.0.1/dumbo/administrator/index.php?option=com_dumbo&view=listings
```

The library structures are not found `(View not found [Name, Typ, Präfix]: listings, html, dumboView)`

I also added the `JLoader::registerPrefix('Mylib', dirname(__FILE__));` into a system plugin (onAfterInitialise Event) without luck.

What am i missing? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add actual views in your components.

Comment: I want the views to be taken from the library. If i add views in the component, that extend from the library views, the model getItems() is getting called twice.

Comment: Hi, first of all it's quite a strange requirement, usually you would use models from a library not views; that said, I don't think you can achieve it. Registering the namespace only tells Joomla where to find Mylib- but as you see in the error message "View not found" the view it's looking for is supposed to be called dumboView. If you want automatic view selection from Joomla, I would use the library as the entry component and let it invoke the models from dumbo and jumbo. Else you could add a task to the controller which explicitly loads the view

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Loading views from the library over the controller is what i done previously. I was just looking for a more clean way. atm i have proxy component views that extend from the library views, but i was looking for a way to have as few elements in the components itself as possible.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're using different file structure and class naming conventions than Joomla! core. This won't work without rewriting related methods such as controller's `getView()`.

That said, using standard naming conventions, I was able to get this to work by setting `base_path` option when fetching the controller in component's entry file:

```
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Mylib', ['base_path' => JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/mylib']);
```

This loads the main controller named `MylibController` and located in `libraries/mylib/controller.php`. Models and views are then loaded correctly from within the component.

However, there could be many issues using a library like this. For instance, if it contains controllers extending from `Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\FormController`, you must set `$option` property to the name of the component currently being used (e.g. `com_dumbo`, you can get this from the input). Otherwise, library prefix `mylib` will be used to build redirect links which results in broken links.

Comment: I already have a library containing working MVC structures for different components. You can use every filestructure that makes sense in the library while registering via jloader. e.g. `JLoader::register('MylibFrontendViewListings', MYLIBPATH_FRAMEWORK . '/frontend/views/listings.php');` Controllers are getting used directly from the library. The question was if for example views can be used from the library without extending like this: `class DumboViewListings extends MylibFrontendViewListings {}`. Just to get everything a bit leaner.

Comment: Having to manually register every class is not an acceptable solution for me. But whatever works for you.

Comment: Thats the way kunena does it for example. Accessing the component name via input is a bad idea, because there is a lot REST stuff going on and the component is not always in GET. It can be just defined via constant on component level. So its possible, i was looking for a leaner way. Still thanks for the try.